# UDP send and receive between two programs in specific ports

Tags: sockets, udp, port

I have a complete program that communicates via UDP protocol. Program runs on a PC with ip 192.168.1.9. When I send specific data, this program responds.

code for sending:

```
var client = new UdpClient();
IPEndPoint destination = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.9"), 1531);
IPAddress localIp = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.3");
IPEndPoint source = new IPEndPoint(localIp, 1530);
client.Client.Bind(source);
client.Connect(destination);
byte[] send_buffer = { 170, 170, 0, 0, 1, 1, 86 };
client.Send(send_buffer, send_buffer.Length);
```

Wireshark captures:
[Screen](http://s16.postimg.org/vn5utvhhh/V_st_i_ek.png)

But my application does not detect anything:

```
    UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(1530);

    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.3");
    IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1530);

    byte[] receive_byte_array;

        while (!done)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for broadcast");
            receive_byte_array = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
        }
```

I need to capture communications from 192.168.9 to 192.168.1.3 on port 1530.

Comment: Why are you using UDP for inter process communication?

Comment: And event then, why are you using specific IPs instead of using the `127.0.0.1` loopback IP?

Comment: Program, which runs on 192.168.1.9 is complete and cannot be changed. UDP communication is already implemented.

Comment: If i use 127.0.0.1 application also does not capture anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your sender is binding to local IP `192.168.1.3` on port 1530 as its source, and then sending data to remote IP `192.168.1.9` on port **1531** as the destination.

Your receiver is binding to local IP `0.0.0.0` on port **1530** for receiving data, and then filtering out any inbound data that was NOT sent from remote port 1530 (which it is).

**The data is not being sent to the port that the receiver is reading on.**

To fix that, you need to either:

1. change your receiver to bind to port `1531` instead of port `1530`:

   ```
   UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(1531);
   ```
2. change your sender to send the data to port `1530` instead of port `1531`:

   ```
   IPEndPoint destination = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.9"), 1530);
   ```

Comment: I have to send via port 1531 but aplication listens on this port. If i use port 1530, application does not respond.

Comment: Read my answer again. The sender is sending from port 1530 to port 1531, but the receiver is NOT listening on port 1531. I told you how to fix that.